# How to Use nodes callback when i want to build a JSON Object Like Below

Tags: json, node.js

I  have just started coding with node.js, I understand that node.js is asynchronous but not sure how to deal with this problem.

I'm querying mysql and building a JSON as follows:

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');
    var async = require('async');
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host : 'localhost',
 user : 'root',
 password : '',
 database : 'hungryna_hungry_database',
 insecureAuth : true
});
var obj={
  "zone":[],
};
var zonearray=new Array();
connection.query('SELECT id,name FROM zone LIMIT 100', function(err, rows) {
 var ck=new Array();
  for(i=0; i < rows.length; i++){
      var zoneObj={};
      var zone=rows[i];
      zoneObj.id=zone.id;
      zoneObj.name=zone.name;
           ck.push({
                "id":zoneObj.id,
                "name":zoneObj.name

            });
            build_actor(zoneObj.id,function(err,area){
              if(!err){

                     //zonearray=ck;
                      //obj.zone=zonearray;
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(ck));
                }
            });

   }
 });

 function build_actor(zoneid,cb){
    connection.query('SELECT id,name FROM area WHERE zone_id='+zoneid+';',
      function(err,       a) {


       var ak =new Array();
       for(var i in a)
       {
            ak.push({
                "id":a[i].id,
                "name":a[i].name
            });
       }

       cb (null,ak);

    });
```

My output is below:

```
    [{"id":1,"name":"Gulshan-Banani-Baridhara-DOHS"},{"id":2,"name":"Uttara"},{"id":
    4,"name":"Dhanmondi-Lalmatia-Mohammadpur"}]
   [{"id":1,"name":"Gulshan-Banani-Baridhara-DOHS"},{"id":2,"name":"Uttara"},{"id":
   4,"name":"Dhanmondi-Lalmatia-Mohammadpur"}]
   [{"id":1,"name":"Gulshan-Banani-Baridhara-DOHS"},{"id":2,"name":"Uttara"},{"id":
   4,"name":"Dhanmondi-Lalmatia-Mohammadpur"}]
```

Output I want is below:

```
       {
       "zone1":[
  {
     "id":1,
     "name":"a",
     "area":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"area1"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"area2"
        }
     ]  
   },
   {
     "id":2,
     "name":"b",
     "area":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"area1"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"area2"
        }
     ]  
   }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: The output you want is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Sorry this is My mistake my JSON IS Blew ` {
   "zone1":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"a",
         "area":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "name":"area1"
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "name":"area2"
            }
         ]  
       },
       {
         "id":2,
         "name":"b",
         "area":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "name":"area1"
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "name":"area2"
            }
         ]  
       }
          ]
        }
`

Comment: Edit your question, the comment is not readable.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but you are far away from getting the desired output. Besides many other things you should learn about JavaScript, maybe a library like 'async' (async.series) or 'Seq' could help you in this special problem.